# Load PHP files inside div when clicking <a> tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to load PHP files inside a div based on what links a user clicks. I want the content to be refreshed only in that div, not the entire page.

My index.php file looks like this:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" id="allrepos" href="#">GitHubAPI</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['userid']))
                    {
                        echo '
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hello, '.$_SESSION['username'].'!</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                My repositories
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" id="myrepos" href="#">All repositories</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" id="mybookmarked" href="#">Bookmarked repositories</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Profile
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Create team</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View teams</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        <a href="github/logout.php" class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>
                                    </div>
                            </li>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 
                            '<li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=">
                                Login
                                </a>
                            </li>';
                    }
                ?>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
         <div id="repositories">
            <?php include 'repositories.php'; ?>
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#allrepos").click(function() {
                    $("#repositories").load('repositories.php');
                    return false;
                })
            });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myrepos").click(function() {
                    $("#repositories").load('myrepositories.php');
                    return false;
                })
            });
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#mybookmarked").click(function() {
                    $("#repositories").load('mybookmarkedrepos.php');
                    return false;
                })
            });
        </script>
```

When the index.php loads, I want the repositories.php to get loaded, then to change what gets displayed in the div with id "repositories" by clicking links.

At the moment nothing happens when I click any of the links.

Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to repeat `document.ready` to wrap every single event handler you declare - just put all your code inside one big document.ready function

Comment: Anyway when you say "nothing happens"...have you checked the browser console for errors? Have you included jQuery in your page correctly? Have you checked the network tab to see if the ajax call (initiated by the "load" command) is occurring, and what it is returning? You don't seem to have done any basic debugging...

Comment: You cannot load php files directly. You can load js, txt, html (static files) directly. For php you need to render it on server side and then use ajax to get the data.

Comment: @HarryBomrah yes, that's exactly what the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) commands in the OP's code are intended to do. The idea is right but evidently, something is interfering with the process...hence my request for debugging info

Comment: @HarryBomrah you can definitely load php files directly ... (include, require) - php side | (.load()) jquery side

Answer (score 1):

Only for this matter , you not gonna need js here , you can do it by php also. here is an example of how it can be done.
Hope this will help you.

```html
        <a href="index.php?page=about"> about </a>
        <a href="index.php?page=contact"> contact </a>
        <a href="index.php?page=service"> service </a>
        <a href="index.php?page=shope"> shop </a>

        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['page'])
            {
               if($_GET['page'] == "about")
                 include'about.php';
               else if($_GET['page'] == "contact")
                include'contact.php'; 
               else if($_GET['page'] == "service")
               include'service.php';
               else if($_GET['page'] == "shope")
               include'shope.php';

            }
        ?>
```